# How do i copy a folder having symbolic link to another directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, command-line, termux

I am trying to copy a folder having symbolic links to another directory

Note - The actual files i intend to copy are different but just for the purpose of this question to make it easy to demonstrate issue , i am giving a example

```
xd003@localhost:~$ ls /data/data/com.termux/files/home/source
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  symlink                                           
xd003@localhost:~$
```

Here's the source folder which has some files and a symbolic link , and the destination folder is empty

```
xd003@localhost:~$ cp -R /data/data/com.termux/files/home/source /sdcard/dest
cp: cannot create symbolic link '/sdcard/dest/source/symlink': Operation not permitted
xd003@localhost:~$
```

I copy the source folder to destination directory but i get an error stating the symlink cannot be copied over , just to confirm i check the destination directory and as expected it didn't copied the symbolic file

```
xd003@localhost:~$ ls /sdcard/dest/source                              
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
xd003@localhost:~$
```

How do i fix this issue and copy the symbolic link in its original state

Edit - After some googling and one answer suggestion below , i tried using cp -LR command .It didn't gave me any error but it copied the symlink as folder and not in its original state , as you can see below the first line itself shows the symlink in destination is copied as a folder and in source , it indeed is a proper symbolic link

```
xd003@localhost:~$ ls -la /sdcard/dest/source | grep "\->"
xd003@localhost:~$ ls /sdcard/dest/source
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  symlink
xd003@localhost:~$ ls -la /data/data/com.termux/files/home/source | grep "\->"
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 xd003 xd003   13 Jun 12 12:40 symlink -> /sdcard/data/
xd003@localhost:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference the links:

```
cp -L -R files/* location/
```

`-L` is used to dereference or `--dereference`

Comment: Okey that's some progress , now I don't get any symbolic link not copied error but if copies the symbolic link as a folder as not in its original state

Comment: @Sachin  I read from [here](https://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-copy-symbolic-links-in-linux/) about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- you zip the entire folder in the original location.
- then sudo copy this zip file to the machine where jenkins is running
- stop jenkins
- sudo unzip -o jenkinslts.zip
- now restart jenkins